# SQL Server summation in a data split in groups

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server code that takes the data of women between 15 and 49 years that have children and split in groups with interval of 5 years, it's calculated the ratio (women in the age group with children / total number of woman of age group). But I want it in the same Query as the summation of the ratios, because of the groups I  don't know how to make this summation in the same query.

```
SELECT CASE
            WHEN age > 14
             AND age < 20 THEN '15-19'
            WHEN age > 19
             AND age < 25 THEN '20-24'
            ...
            WHEN age > 44
             AND age < 50 THEN '45-49'
       END AS age_interval,
       ROUND(CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN have_children = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS float) / COUNT(*), 2) AS ratio
FROM DataBase
WHERE sex = 'woman';
```

Comment: I don't follow what your question is here; what are you asking?

Comment: Side note, for your second `WHEN` you can just have `age < 25` (and the same for the latter); you already know the value is greater than or equal to `20`, due to the first `WHEN` not being true

Comment: I  *hope* as well, you don't *really* have a table called `Database`. `FROM Database` is somewhat confusing, as you don't `SELECT` data from a `DATABASE`, you `SELECT` from an object like a `TABLE` or `VIEW`; which are on a `SCHEMA` within a `DATABASE`.

Comment: You would just group by your (hopefully simplified via the suggestion from @Larnu) case expression.